# How to choose number of bins in a dc.js barchart?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have created a bar chart in `dc.js`:

```
d3.csv("input.csv", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (x) {
        x.x = +x.x;
    });

    var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                return Math.floor(parseFloat(d['x']) * 10) / 10; 
            });
    var group1 = dim1.group(),

    chart = dc.barChart("#barchart");

    chart
        .width(500)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(dim1)
        .group(group1)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,3]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .barPadding([0.4])

    chart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d});
    chart.yAxis().ticks(10);
});
```

But the number of bars is low. I want to increase the number of bars displayed to 12.

How can I choose the number of bars?

Comment: Is the number, by any chance, 4?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no, why?

Comment: I thought I'd worked out the solution. How many bars are there?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It depends on the data, but in this case it's 8

Comment: The number of bins is determined by the way you define your group and dimension using crossfilter. So you'd have to show that part of your code for folks to help you out.

Comment: @Gordon thanks, edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines determine the number of bins:

```
dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return Math.floor(parseFloat(d['x']) * 10) / 10; 
        });
var group1 = dim1.group(),
```

What you are doing here is rounding down to the previous tenth (0.1). Thus any rows with x equal to 1.12, 1.16, 1.19 will be counted in the 1.1 bin, etc.

If you want an exact number of bins, you'll have to determine the range of x and divide that by the number of bins you want. If you don't need anything that exact, you could just fiddle with the number 10 there until you get what you want.

For example, changing it to

```
dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return Math.floor(parseFloat(d['x']) * 20) / 20; 
        });
var group1 = dim1.group(),
```

will give you twice as many bins, because it will round down to the previous twentieth (0.05).

So 1.12 would round to 1.10; and 1.16, 1.19 would round to 1.15, etc.

BTW, `parseFloat` is unnecessary, because you have already converted x to number with `x.x = +x.x`

Comment: but if I increase the number (10) the space between the bins becomes negative and the barChart doesnt look like a barChart anymore. I tried changing the barPadding value too, but with no result

Comment: It's an unfortunate design, but you also need `.xUnits` in order to tell the chart how many bars there are, in order for it to determine the bar width. I'm not sure how you got away without specifying it before - the default is `dc.units.integers` which is incorrect for those bins. You'd want `dc.units.fp.precision(0.1)` for your original example, or `dc.units.fp.precision(0.05)` for what I show above.

Comment: And yeah, `barPadding` only affects charts with an ordinal x scale. Personally I think this was generalized in a stupid way (allowing different width bars for different months) but some people depend on those features so we are kind of stuck with it unless we want to break a lot of code.

Comment: Ah I see. I also didn't know about `dc.units.fp.precision`, thank you for that. Now I can manipulate the bars however I want to